# Is it possible to read a PDF line by line?

Tags: java, pdf

Is there a way in Java, to read a PDF line by line and convert it to text?  I have used iTextPDFParser previously but it reads page by page rather than line by line.  This has a few drawbacks. Let me know if there is any way to read PDF's line by line.

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaPDF/article.html

Comment: Thanks Benjamin. 
But PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(OUTPUTFILE)); document.open(); PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(INPUTFILE); int n = reader.getNumberOfPages(); PdfImportedPage page; // Go through all pages
This PDF reader reads PDF page by Page , Can u pls suggest me on reading line by line on PDF

Comment: http://www.quicklyjava.com/read-pdf-file-in-java-using-itext/

Answer (score 3):

Before you start on this, you should ask yourself a few more abstract questions.  The first is "what is a line of text in a document?"  The problem, you see, is that PDF represents a very large set of printable documents (I won't say **all**, but it's pretty close).

Text is placed on the page with a number of operators: `Tj` `'` `"` `TJ`. For example `(a string) Tj` places "a string" in the current font with the current text transformations (word/char spacing/scaling, transformation matrix) on the page. And even this is over simplified because the 8-bit characters in the string may be interpreted in all kinds of screwy ways depending on the encoding used for this instance of the font.

So let's look at it this way - if you place text on a page in lines, a generating application might very well use the `'` operator which moves to the next line and places a line of text.  This is great, extracting line by line is easy.  If an application decides to place all the plain text on the page and then all the italic text and then all the bold text (I'm looking at *you* troff), then you don't get things in the order you expect.  In fact, an application can place the text on the page in any possible order that you want.

OK, you say, just take the text and sort it in reading order.  That's easy.  You get the bounding boxes for each piece of text and do a sort from top to bottom left to right.  What about columns?  What about inset boxes? What about [small caps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_caps) or initial [drop caps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial)?  What about sub and superscript?  What about text on a map that follows the contours of a road or river?  What *is* the reading order anyway?  What if the text is Kanji?  What if it's a a mix of Kanji and English?  What if it's Hebrew with numbers?  What about [ligatures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographic_ligature)?  Where are word boundaries anyway?  What if a word was placed a glyph at a time?  How do I know when a glyph is part of a word and I should put in a space?  What if there were no spaces placed on the page?  What about [discretionary hyphens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_hyphen)?

This gives you an idea of the scope of the problem and things you will need to consider when interpreting the output of typical text extraction.  Most PDF text extraction tools go as far as pulling the text, undoing the encoding, annealing words and sorting.

I worked on text extraction tools in Acrobat 1.0 and 2.0 and we hit just about everything in that list.  We had one engineer/researcher working full time on the text extraction code in the 2.0 product and he started during the middle of the 1.0 product - that's close to two years to get that right(ish).

So you want line by line?  Roll up your sleeves.